# Converting the deformation gradient from Cartesian to Cylindrical

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, solid-mechanics

Suppose I have a Cartesian deformation gradient tensor **F** for a domain $\Omega_0$. This tensor deforms $\Omega_0$ into a new domain $\Omega_1$. Also assume that I know the values for each entry of **F** at every point of $\Omega_0$. However, this tensor is in Cartesian coordinates.

1. Is there a conversion formula that would convert **F** into the Cylindrical version at each point?

My final goal is to find the opening angle using the circumferential stretch from the cylindrical deformation gradient but for some reason I can only calculate the Cartesian version directly.

2. Is there a way to calculate the opening angle via the Cartesian stretches? If so you can ignore the first question.

Comment: $\begin{aligned}F\left( \Omega _{0}\right) =G\\
\Omega _{0}\rightarrow \Omega _{1}\\
G\rightarrow J^{T}GJ\\
J=\dfrac {\partial \Omega _{0}}{\partial \Omega _{1}}\end{aligned}\\$

Comment: This is your general transformation rules. Where J the jacobi matrix